# Copy & Paste multiple cells & rows in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns, copy-paste

I have to copy multiple rows in VBA excel repeatedly.

Does anyone knows some shorter solution how to make this?

My current solution looks like this:

```
'Select row with sun altitude values
Range("A11:A277").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("EE11:EE277").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'Select row 11
Range("B11:EB11").Copy
Range("EF11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF37").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF41").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF71").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF101").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF131").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF161").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF191").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF221").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF251").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'Select column B and paste in every next columns
Range("B11:B277").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("EF11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("FU11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("FX11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("HM11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("HQ11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("JF11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

In general I have to copy 10 the same rows and at least 6 the same columns.
The **exact distance between every row is 30 interspersed in every 26**, as per above and in the picture attached.
I have seen previous solution for copy multiple cells in VBA provided, however it refers more for issues with external workbooks.

Thanks & regards,[image]

Comment: And what is the issue with your code? Any errors? What is your question? You didn't ask one yet.

Comment: Hi,

I would like to make my code shorter when possible. Do you know any solution how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By combining the Areas into one Range with Commas.  So this:

```
'Select row 11
Range("B11:EB11").Copy
Range("EF11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF37").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF41").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF71").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF101").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF131").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF161").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF191").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF221").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("EF251").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

becomes

```
'Select row 11
Range("B11:EB11").Copy
Range("EF11,EF37,EF41,EF71,EF101,EF131,EF161,EF191,EF221,EF251").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

If the Rows are pasted at a regular interval, you could use a Loop, either to pate, or to build a Range

```
For i = 1 to 17 Step 4 'Paste every 4 rows
    Cells(136,i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Paste in column EF, a.k.a. column 136
Next i
```

or

```
Set RngTmp = Cells(136,1)
For i = 5 to 17 Step 4 'Paste every 4 rows
    Set RngTmp = Union(RngTmp, Cells(136,i)) 'Add the next cell to the range
Next i
RngTmp.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Paste to all cells in the range
```

Comment: Hi,

Could you tell me what means the 136 value? Thanks

Comment: @MariuszKrukar `Column 136` is `Column EF`, in the same way that `Column 2` is `Column B`, `Column 26` is `Column Z` or `Column 27` is `Column AA` - the `Worksheet.Cells([row],[column])` property takes numbers for the Row and Column

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line. For example, your copy/paste of row 11 can be done:

```
Range("B11:EB11").Copy
Range("EF11, EF37, EF41, EF71, <all the others in your list> , EF251").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

That is, you list all the cell destinations separated by commas, in quotes.