# VBA Excel paste to the columns in regular intervals

Tags: excel, vba

I have the same set of data defined in the range, which I would like to populate across multiple columns down to the end.
[image]

By the following thread:
[Copy & Paste multiple cells & rows in VBA excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51928919/copy-paste-multiple-cells-rows-in-vba-excel)

I usedd this formula:

```
   Dim l As Long
   For l = 23 To 43 Step 6
   Cells(l, 15).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
   Next l
```

UPDATE:

I tried also:

```
   Dim l As Long
   For l = Range("W1").Column To Range("AQ1").Column Step 6
   Rows(13).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
   Next l
```

But it didn't work

How could I make the regular copy across the columns (every 6th column)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim sRng As Range, i As Long
    Dim endCol As Long, iRow As Long
    Const SRC_RANGE = "B13:E22" ' Source range
    Const ISTEP = 6 ' interval is 6 cols
    Const END_COL = "AL" ' or 38
    ' Get the end col #
    endCol = Cells(1, END_COL).Column
    ' Get the source range
    Set sRng = Range(SRC_RANGE)
    iRow = sRng.Row
    ' Loop through and copy it over
    For i = sRng.Column + ISTEP To endCol Step ISTEP
        sRng.Copy Cells(iRow, i)
    Next
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Copy method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144104)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code copies a range of cells to specific columns with a defined step between them. If there are more than one column in the range the target range top left cell will be the intersection of the startrow and the defined columns

```
Sub colcopy()

Const startcol = "C"  'this is the first column's letter to paste
Const stopcol = "X"   'this is the last column's letter to paste
Const period = 6      'the value of the column's step
Const firstrow = 8    'the first cell's row in a column to paste
Set copyrange = Range("A1:A6")  'the range to copy
copyrange.Copy

startcolvalue = Columns(startcol).Column
stopcolvalue = Columns(stopcol).Column
For i = startcolvalue To stopcolvalue Step period
Cells(firstrow, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll


Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate that you use Const definitions. However, please don't use undeclared variables (copyrange, startcolvalue, stopcolvalue). SO is full of questions related to code that doesn't use `Option Explicit` and doesn't declare variables. And please indent your code properly.